# In mathematics, what is a placeholder?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, notation, math-history

Google defines the word **placeholder** in the following image: [image]

My question is: Is this the only definition of the word **placeholder** in mathematics?

I am thinking along the lines:

> If $M = p^k m^2$ is a (hypothetical) number, and it logically follows (from known properties of $M$) that the condition $k = 1$ always holds, then $k$ is a **placeholder** for $1$.

Your thoughts?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder) offers $4$ interpretations, i.e., free variable,  interpolated variable, Metasyntactic variable, Format placeholder. Do you want a definition for  prime divisors of integers ?

Comment: "A significant zero in the decimal representation of a number" appears to me to be an _extremely_ marginal mathematical meaning of "placeholder". I'd say that Google's AI algorithms done goofed here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I actually want a definition for **placeholder** involving the *valuation* $k = \nu_{p}(M)$ of the number $M = p^k m^2$, where $p$ is prime.

Comment: I dimly recall seeing somewhere that there is a certain *theory of places* (and that, that theory is *mathematical*).  Can anybody confirm if this is correct?

Comment: I am not too sure though, whether that *theory of places* has anything to say regarding *placeholders*.

Comment: I found a reference to *Primes and places* in this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_theory#Primes_and_places) under **Algebraic number theory**.